# Ububtu 20.04 hangs at the start of live, and of install. Also tried with live and install Ububtu Studio

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I just had to redo my complete pc. It had windows 7 and Kubuntu. I much prefer the latter.
On the rebuild, I installed first a windows 8.1 Pro.
Since I want to start doing some music (bass and guitar) i decided to go for Ubuntu Studio. I use Win just occasionally, for things not OPen Source

I can boot from DVD, and i get the menu for live, and all the other possibilities. Either live or install, The setup starts with the little 3 part spinner turning and that's it. NADA.

I tried with the memory test, and it seems to freeze within a minute or so.

Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit is installed and running.

PC is an old HP Z200.
Processor Intel Core i3... 530 @ 2.93GHz
Ram 8.00GB (7.87GB usable)
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

video card is  Nvidia quadro K620. (Open to going back to OnBoard video...)
Soundblaster X-fi Fatali7y platinum (with 1/4" jacks and Rca, and din plugs in front).
This last is the main reason for wanting Studio. I would however be fine with Ubuntu and work from Guitarix.

This has to be something from Bios???
Tried Live on a Toshiba laptop with 2GB memory and live loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i've got it!
Win 8.1 does not completely shutdown because there is a fast reboot option there that affects things and could cause problems.

I changed it to NOT use fast boot and i purged all the temp files. Ubuntu studio 20.04 loaded like a charm.

keep in mind i'm no expert...but it worked.